# How do I make a folder in my GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I'm a new user in GitHub and I want to make a folder for each problem of Project Euler, but I haven't been able to find a way to create a folder in my repository. Below is the screenshot of my repository.

[image]

Comment: Rename files like this: `foldername/README.md`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename files like this: `foldername/README.md`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have cloned your repo to your local machine, go inside the repo directory, and simply create new folders for each problem. Then move the files inside the folders, and finally update your repo by running these commands:

`git add .`

`git commit -m "message"`

`git push`

Hope this helps!